# fancyheaders definition ornament

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I would like to add some part of code related with ornaments in chapter name to my fancy header definision file.

```
% Datei fancyheaders.tex
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   % Paket laden
\pagestyle{fancy}   % bereitgestelltes Layout 'fancy' laden

 \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

  \makeatletter
  \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
   \vspace*{50\p@}%
   {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
   %\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    %    \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    %    \par\nobreak
    %    \vskip 20\p@
    %\fi
     \interlinepenalty\@M
      \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
     \vskip 40\p@
        }}
   \makeatother





\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\chapnumfont}{%     % define font for chapter number
\usefont{T1}{pnc}{b}{n}%      % choose New Chancery, bold, normal shape
\fontsize{100}{100}%          % font size 100pt, baselineskip 100pt
\selectfont%                  % activate font
}
\colorlet{chapnumcol}{gray!100}  % color for chapter number

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filleft\bfseries}
{\filleft\chapnumfont\textcolor{chapnumcol}{\thechapter}}
{-24pt}
{\Huge}


\fancyhead{}
%\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}%{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}%{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}



% Style "plain" berschreiben, das bei 
%\chapter{...} mit aktiviert wird
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}}
```

And add this (when put in to chapter file it destroying fancy hdr setting). Woudl like to add this code to upper definition.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedleft}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=3cm,align=center] (chapnum)
 {\fontsize{100}{130}\color{gray}\selectfont\thechapter};%
\node[shift={(-1cm,10pt)},anchor=north west](CNW)
  at (chapnum.north west) {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{7}};
\node[shift={(1cm,10pt)},anchor=north east](CNE)
  at (chapnum.north east) {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=v]{7}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
{0pt}
{\Huge}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are trying to achieve?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\chapnumfont}{%     % define font for chapter number
\usefont{T1}{pnc}{b}{n}%      % choose New Chancery, bold, normal shape
\fontsize{100}{100}%          % font size 100pt, baselineskip 100pt
\selectfont%                  % activate font
}
\colorlet{chapnumcol}{gray!100}  % color for chapter number

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\filleft}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=3cm,align=center,inner sep=0pt] (chapnum)
       {\chapnumfont\color{chapnumcol}\thechapter};%
    \node[shift={(-1cm,0pt)},anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt](CNW)
      at (chapnum.north west) {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{7}};
    \node[shift={(1cm,0pt)},anchor=north east,inner sep=0pt](CNE)
      at (chapnum.north east) {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=v]{7}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
  {0pt}
  {\Huge}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{1}% just for the example
\chapter{Title for a long test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I suppressed from the original code the parts that were not relevant to the issue with the ornaments; for example, those associated to the `fancyhdr` package. Don't forget to include them in your actual document.

In a comment it has been requested to produce a similar design for the Table of Contents; this can be done using `\titleformat` with the `numberless` key. Below I show one possibility (noe titlesec is loaded with the `explicit` option):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\chapnumfont}{%     % define font for chapter number
\usefont{T1}{pnc}{b}{n}%      % choose New Chancery, bold, normal shape
\fontsize{100}{100}%          % font size 100pt, baselineskip 100pt
\selectfont%                  % activate font
}
\colorlet{chapnumcol}{gray!100}  % color for chapter number

\newcommand\MyOrnament[1]{%
  \makebox[3.8em][#1]{%
    \raisebox{.5\height}{\pgfornament[width=1cm]{7}}}%
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\filleft}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=3cm,align=center,inner sep=0pt] (chapnum)
       {\chapnumfont\color{chapnumcol}\thechapter};%
    \node[shift={(-1cm,0pt)},anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt](CNW)
      at (chapnum.north west) {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{7}};
    \node[shift={(1cm,0pt)},anchor=north east,inner sep=0pt](CNE)
      at (chapnum.north east) {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=v]{7}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
  {0pt}
  {\Huge#1}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\filleft}
  { }
  {0pt}
  {\MyOrnament{l}{\Huge#1}\MyOrnament{r}}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\setcounter{chapter}{1}% just for the example
\chapter{Title for a long test chapter}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC:

[image]

Comment: Thaks, that work perfect.

Comment: How complex can be adding ornament to the table of contents? {\tableofcontents
\newpage
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LoF}
\listoffigures}

Comment: @user35815 where should the ornaments appear for the table of contents?

Comment: Think, the same patern as in chapter but a bit smaller

Comment: @user35815 it's not difficult, but in what position should the ornaments go? The table of contents has no number to surround with the ornaments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12984/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-user35815)

Comment: @user35815 I've edited my answer providing an option for unnumbered chapters.

Comment: well, my first thought was to put ornaments shortly before table of concent and shortly behind in the same line.. Don't know if this will be aesthetic but it worth to try.

Comment: @user35815 Please see my updated answer. Something like that?

Comment: Yes, thank you this is awesome, but there are come complications: "You can't use macro-parameter charakter #" in vertical mode, so when i deleted it whole dokument compile fine but the chapters names and ToF, ToC... are small like a normal text

Comment: @user35815 Did you used explicit in `titlesec`? I forgot to mention that in  the second example. You need to load `titlesec` in this way: `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}`. Let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: "Option clash for package titlesec"

Comment: @user35815 Don't load the package twice. Check your preamble and load it only once with the option I mentioned.

Comment: Exactly. Last queston :)\

Comment: Set margin in ToC in the same line as ornaments in chapter names

Comment: @user35815 Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @user35815 You're welcome! :)